# #1442 - Can't update table 'passenger' in stored trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling, triggers, mysql-connector

Cant solve the error

Code

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insertDetails` AFTER INSERT ON `passenger` 
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE passenger
INNER JOIN trains ON (trains.train_no = passenger.train_no)
SET passenger.train_name = trains.train_name,
passenger.startPlace = trains.startPlace,
passenger.destination = trains.destination
```

and now i am getting error as above.`

i included the train_no as a foreign key from the trains table
i want to make a my database such that it automatically include remaining data from the trains table.
so i wrote a trigger

Comment: You must not UPDATE the table but SET according values to `NEW.column_name`.

Comment: Why are you copying this data from the train table at all? Duplicated data just leads to opportunities for inconsistencies later.

Comment: If a train has a route a>>d passing through b and c is it not enough to know there is 1 or more passengers entraining or detraining at each node?

Answer (score 1):

Extensively:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `insertDetails` 
AFTER INSERT ON `passenger` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.train_name  = (SELECT train_name  FROM trains WHERE train_no = NEW.train_no),
    NEW.startPlace  = (SELECT startPlace  FROM trains WHERE train_no = NEW.train_no),
    NEW.destination = (SELECT destination FROM trains WHERE train_no = NEW.train_no);
```

Of course it is reasonable to declare local variables, obtain according data into them from `trains` with one `SELECT INTO` (instead of 3 separate subqueries) then set these values to newly inserted row. But I hope thay you can do it yourself.